# regex, period allowed, not comma

Tags: regex

Hi Im looking for a regex for

Valid:

```
20000
20.000
```

If a comma is used, it should not match with the comma and whats after.
Not valid

```
20.000,12
```

Right now Im using:

```
([0-9]+([.][0-9]+)*)+?
```

But this one also takes the last 2 digits after comma.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```
^\d+(?:\.\d+)*
# start of line, 1+ digits, .1234 eventually
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/cEW8me/1/).

Answer (score 2):

If you add a ^ to the beginning of the regex, only the part from the start of the string will match

```
^([0-9]+([.][0-9]+)*)+?
```

But i think

```
^\d+(\.\d+)*
```

is the better solution to match numbers

Comment: This only returns 45000, none of the others on the image

Comment: @RasmusBidstrup Add the `m` modifier so that `^` matches the beginning of each line, not just the beginning of the whole string.

Comment: as i wrote - it matches the first occurrence in the string.

Comment: @Barmar We are getting closer, now it accepts 45000 and 45.000, but still not 1.000.000 or 23000,00

Answer (score -1):

If you want to match floating point numbers then use `(^\d*.?\d+)`

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing in the question that suggests that the outcome needs to be a valid number. Therefore it looks like the expression needs to accept any number or a period in which case the regex is quite straightforward and the following should work:

```
^([0-9\.]+)$
```

Here are my tests to demonstrate the outcome

```
20000 - pass
20.000 - pass
20.000,12 - fail
1.000.000 - pass
23000,000 - fail
```

For info, I used the php code below for my test:

```
$testdata = array('20000', '20.000', '20.000,12', '1.000.000', '23000,000');
$pattern = "/^([0-9\.]+)$/";
foreach ($testdata as $k => $v) {
    $result = preg_match($pattern, $v)? 'pass': 'fail';
    echo "".$v." - ".$result."<br />";
}
```